# In jinja, can I list all variables passed to the render() function?

Tags: jinja2

Is it possible to access, in jinja, all variables passed to the render function as dict, without knowing their names?

```
from jinja2 import Template

template_vars = {"environment": "dev", "var1": "value1", "var2" : "value2", ... , "var12": "value12", ... ,  "varN": "valueN"}

api_payload = Template("template.json.j2").render(template_vars)
```

Goal of the template is to create a json file like. Here is base for jinja2.

```
{
  "env": "{{environment}}",
  {% for item in [my list of variables passed] %}
    {% if '2 'if item %}
     "{{item}}": "{{item}}"
    {% endif %}
  {% endofr %}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over dictionary like,

```
for key, value in d.items():
   # do whatever with key and value
```

Or you could pass the data as a list and iterate over it too.

Comment: thanks. unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. I've added more details to my to better explain the problem.